# JSP onload call servlet without scriptlets

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I want that when my JSP is loaded to call a servlet. I have this link:

```
<a href="ContentServlet?action=userContents">Homepage</a>
```

But this way I have to click the link, I want to perform the calling automatically when the jsp is loaded.

On the other side I need to use no scriptlets. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although its marked as resolved but I am editing my answer for future reference:
Apart from the javascript solution you can accomplish this with 2 more options using jsp tags:

**Option1:**
You can forward the request to the corresponding servlet.
Use jsp standard action jsp:forward, e.g.:

```
<jsp:forward page="ContentServlet?action=userContents" >
</jsp:forward>
```

You can replace your link with the above tag and the servlet will be called.

**Option2:**
you can redirect the request to your servlet using JSTL tags:

```
<c:redirect url="ContentServlet?action=userContents" />
```

Again you can replace your link with the above tag.

In Option1 browser's url will not change.
In Option 2 browser's url will change to "ContentServlet?action=userContents"

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use JavaScript?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function redirect(){
        window.location = "/ContentServlet?action=userContents"
        }
</script>

    ...

    <body onLoad="redirect()">
```

Comment: I was thinking for a way without javascript, with EL for example, do you know smth like that?

Comment: ok however as I see no one is responding here. I will vote up your answer, thank you anyway :)

Comment: It's either JavaScript or using response.sendRedirect() in Scriptlet code. - But if I understood you correctly, scriptlets are off the table.